# How can I let a plugin.dll call functions of core-application?

Tags: c#, plugins, reflection

okay. So I want to build up a program, that acts as a core for "plugin"-modules.
Another developer could create a plugin1.dll and add it to the "modules" folder to enhance the functionality of my core-application.

**So lets say my core has as example those functionalities:**

- Logging
- User Authentification
- User Interface

As example we have our core-application as mentioned above and someone wants to add a plugin that lets an user see the current time and log it into a standard-log.txt.

**So he would create a class-library that has the functionality:**

- get the current time (functionality included in the .dll)
- display the current time (functionality included in the .dll)
- log the current time (functionality included in the core)

Now my problem is, I can invoke the functionalities of the plugin easily from my core-application using reflection, but how would I the other way around?
How can my plugin1.dll access and invoke the fully-set up logging-functionality of the core-program?

I hope you got my question. I want my plugin1.dll to be able to call as example Logging-methods of my core-class.

Thanks!

Comment: Provide a shared assembly with interfaces, now both sides can work with these abstractions.

Comment: @thehennyy That was also my first idea. Move all the functionalities that are shared, used by modules and core-application to an assembly that is implemented by them all. I am not quite sure how it would work though. Could you provide me a simple example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to separate your problem into two aspects:

1. How can the plugins know what functions are available in the core
   application (at compile-time)?
2. How can they actually invoke those function (at run-time)?

An answer to the first aspect, is to create a separate interface-dll, that defines one (or more) interfaces that the core application will provide. Note that this should contain ONLY the interface definitions, no implementation. A plugin-developer can then import that dll, and program against that interface (without needing a dependency on your complete core implementation).

An answer to the second aspect: You could demand from your plugins to expose a well-known entry-point for initialization. In that method you could provide them a reference to your core implementation as an argument, so that they can store that reference and invoke methods on that interface as needed.

A simple example could look similar to the following:

**Interface dll:**

```
public interface ICoreApplication
{
    //These are the methods that you want to provide to your plugins:
    void LogMessage(string msg);
    //void SomeOtherMethod(...)
    //...
}

public interface IPlugin
{
    //These are the methods that you expect from your plugins:
    void Init(ICoreApplication coreReference);
}
```

*(BTW: The IPlugin interface could also contain additional methods, if you alredy know the functionality that you expect your plugins to provide. In that case, you would not have to invoke your plugins via reflection, but via that interface.)*

**Core application:**

```
public class Core : ICoreApplication
{
    public void InitPlugins()
    {
        IPlugin somePlugin = ...; //retrieve via reflection
        somePlugin.Init(this);
    }
}
```

Note that this is just a simple example, to illustrate the basic concept. There is much more to providing a robust plugin-architecture. You need to think about things like

- Security (Can you trust your plugins? Can you trust the file system from where you load them?)
- Error-handling (What happens if a plugin throws an exception? What if it wants to notify you about an "expected failure"?)
- Threading (If you invoke your plugins on your main thread, they can block your whole application. If you invoke them on some other thread, you need to think about synchronization. What if a plugin creates a new thread and invokes your core application on that thread?)
- etc...